# Rate an Android app using widget

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application.I want to add a rating functionality to it.So that user can rate my app in android market(google Play).Can anyone tell me how to do it with rating bar widget?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rate from within the app yet (apparently coming soon), until then use a library like: https://github.com/codechimp-org/AppRater

Answer (score 0):

There are no public Google Play Store APIs, and the unofficial ones do not provide a method of rating an application either.

You can gently remind your users to rate your application themselves.

While your intentions may be good, creating up a rating API would open up the Play Store to applications falsifying ratings.